# Azure AD B2C provider settings for portals

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-ad-b2c

I read this article [Azure AD B2C provider settings for portals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/azure-ad-b2c) . I'm wondering if there is a simple path that can be extended to Office 365, specifically SharePoint Online.

Comment: Do you want to use B2C as IDP to allow B2C AD users to sign in to Office 365?

Answer (score 0):

**At this time, there is no easy way to allow access to Office 365 using Azure AD B2C.**

You can support this feature ask and get updates on its progress by voting for it in the Azure AD B2C feedback forum: [Integrate Office 365 to work with B2C](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/16849006-aadb2c-integrate-office-365-to-work-with-b2c).